# Zombie villager stole my items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Was trying to cure a zombie. I Succeeded but during the healing process it killed me.  Then it up and **stole all of my items including my elytra**.  It did not leave anything, it took it all.  He got cured before I could get back to him.  I killed him, and he didn't drop anything.  I dug around the area and none of my items were to be found.

Is this an intended feature or a weird bug? I assume I can't get my stuff back.

Comment: I quickly tested it in creative. All zombie villagers dropped their elytra when the conversion finished

Comment: Did they perhaps despawn? All loose items despawn after 5 minutes

Comment: I think it's ten minutes actually.  The chunks weren't loaded cause it was far away from my spawnpoint.  Unless a zombie villager that is in the process of converting keeps the chunks loaded?  That could be it.  I *think* i got there before ten minutes was over but i cant be postitive.

Comment: Any mob that gets converted will drop all equipped items (armor, weapons, or anything else in their hand) once they are done converting (I know this because I once made a Zombie drowner to get Nautilus shells from the Drowned Zombies, also Husks that are underwater for too long become regular Zombies), but I only have tried this with regular Zombies, so I'm not sure if this works on Zombie Villagers (I do know that armor is not shown on any type Villager, but is still active).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your spawn point was too far away so the items despawned, but if not, it's a bug.